Debian doesn't recognise Desktop directory, and instead uses the entire home directory as the desktop
I was recently messing around with my Desktop directory, and I screwed it up rather badly.
I had a backup, so I deleted the directory, and replaced it with the backup. Problem is, now Debian doesn't recognise this home directory as anything but a normal directory, and so it's confused, and now uses my entire home directory as the desktop.
I've tried rebooting to see if that helps, however with no effect. Same with creating a new user.
How could I get Debian to recognise the Desktop directory and use it as intended? I am using Debian 12, with XFCE.

Special directories are defined in ~/.config/user-dirs.dirs. Some desktop environments have a service which checks if the directories have been removed and updates the file accordingly. Change the XDG_DESKTOP_DIR parameter back to:
XDG_DESKTOP_DIR="$HOME/Desktop"

or something different like:
XDG_DESKTOP_DIR="$HOME/.local/share/Desktop"

if you would prefer it to not clutter the home directory.
Note that the path must literally start with $HOME/.
